# Include aggregate function results in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all the data from a view including the number of times a person has donated money.

The query below selects all people who have donated more than twice.

```
SELECT [Full Name], COUNT(Religious) 'Number of times donated to religious needs'
FROM vw_profileFact
GROUP BY [Full Name]
HAVING COUNT(Religious) > 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

[image: query results]

The query below selects all data from a view related to each person who has donated more than twice.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_profileFact
WHERE Person_Id IN (SELECT Person_Id
                    FROM vw_profileFact
                    GROUP BY Person_Id
                    HAVING COUNT(Religious) > 2)
GO
```

[image: Results of the query can be seen here]

I want to add a column to the query above that would show the number of times a person has donated. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT pf.*
FROM (SELECT pf.*, COUNT(Religious) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_Id) as num_religious_donations
      FROM vw_profileFact pf
     ) pf
WHERE num_religious_donations > 2;
```

Comment: How could I achieve the same thing but instead using a different view for data in the select? 
The views share Person_Id key so I joined on that and received 2k rows back.

SELECT pf.[Full Name], d.DateOfBirth, d.Gender, d.SSN, d.Gender, d.Race, d.HobbyInterest, 
d.PhysicalDescription, pf.num_religious_donations
FROM (SELECT pf.*, COUNT(Religious) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_Id) as num_religious_donations
      FROM vw_profileFact pf
     ) pf
JOIN vw_dossier  d
ON d.Person_Id = pf.Person_Id
WHERE num_religious_donations > 2
ORDER BY num_religious_donations DESC;

Comment: @MantasStanionis . . . I think you should ask a new question.  Your commend is quite complicated.